# Repeating a crosstab element with different parameters

Tags: eclipse, birt, crosstab

I'm a new BIRT user, and I've been having trouble trying to get the behavior I want for my report. I've created a vertically-oriented crosstab with row groupings on month + year. However, each grouping has completely different columns and this ends up with a lot of empty space. It looks like this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/88pykxp.png]

Note all that empty space. It makes the report end up being huge, horizontally. I'd like it to be closer to something like this (quick mock-up):

[image: http://i.imgur.com/QI3wiU8.png]

Right now, the report is generated based on start and end date report parameters, and it looks fine with just one month. I was thinking I could have the crosstab in its entirety be repeated, each one with its own single-month time period, but I cannot find any way to do this. Would that be the correct way of doing this? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to do it. I made the crosstab a sub-report of a scripted dataset of time periods, and then filtered the crosstab on those time periods. Feels sort of hacky and I gotta think there's a better way of doing it, but at least I've got what I wanted.